# Implementing [Authorize] in ASP.NET MVC6 EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to implement the [Authorize] filter in MVC6. Whatever I try I get the error:

> The type of namespace 'Authorize' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to use a bunch of namespaces but either they didn't exist or it didn't work.

I'm really stuck on this one (and using Filters in general), so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The authorization attribute is part of the namespace **Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization**

Check out the documentation [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/index.html)

Comment: Jup, it is! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Few result I got after lot of googling about authorization in mvc 6:

http://senvichet.com/create-custom-attribute-with-action-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-6/

http://www.rosengren.me/blog/global-authorization-attribute-filter-mvc6-vnext-aspnet5/

http://ambracode.com/index/show/7594

Please do share some links if you get sucess implimeting mvc6 authorization with the community.